# Creating thumbnail from an uploaded image in Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, image, joomla, resize

I'm really new to joomla, I don't have idea what should I do to make it done. I just have this kind of code in administrator table, it refers to uploading files.

```
                //Support for file field: cover
            if(isset($_FILES['jform']['name']['cover'])):         
                jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
                jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
                $file = $_FILES['jform'];

                //Check if the server found any error.
                $fileError = $file['error']['cover'];
                $message = '';
                if($fileError > 0 && $fileError != 4) {
                    switch ($fileError) :
                        case 1:
                            $message = JText::_( 'File size exceeds allowed by the server');
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $message = JText::_( 'File size exceeds allowed by the html form');
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $message = JText::_( 'Partial upload error');
                            break;
                    endswitch;
                    if($message != '') :
                        JError::raiseWarning(500,$message);
                        return false;
                    endif;
                }
                else if($fileError == 4){
                    if(isset($array['cover_hidden'])):;
                        $array['cover'] = $array['cover_hidden'];
                    endif;
                }
                else{

                    //Check for filesize
                    $fileSize = $file['size']['cover'];
                    if($fileSize > 10485760):
                        JError::raiseWarning(500, 'File bigger than 10MB' );
                        return false;
                    endif;

                    //Replace any special characters in the filename
                    $filename = explode('.',$file['name']['cover']);
                    $filename[0] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/i", "-", $filename[0]);


                    //Add Timestamp MD5 to avoid overwriting
                    $filename = md5(time()) . '-' . implode('.',$filename);
                    $uploadPath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'components'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'com_comic'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'images'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename;
                    $fileTemp = $file['tmp_name']['cover'];

                    if(!JFile::exists($uploadPath)):

                        if (!JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath)):

                            JError::raiseWarning(500,'Error moving file');

                            return false;

                        endif;

                    endif;
                    $array['cover'] = $filename;
                }

            endif;
```

I could upload the file (in this case, an image) from the codes above, but what I'll do next is creating a thumbnail for the uploaded image. I searched for the php codes through the internet but it doesn't seem to work since I can't synchronize it into joomla codes. Umm.. I've made a folder named thumbnail in images folder. So what should I do next?

I'll be so happy and grateful if any of you could help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Joomla has an api (JImage) that will handle resizing for you.

Comment: Yes, I've been checking the api, i'm working with it right now also checking di3sel's codes either.

Answer (score 3):

Well i can share technique I'm using, i hope it will help:

In table's method **check** after the all validation is done (at the end of the method, just before returning true) i add the following code:

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$files = $input->files->get('jform');
if (!is_null($files) && isset($files['image']))
  $this->image = $this->storeImage($files['image']);
```

The i create a new method called **storeImage()** :

```
protected $_thumb = array('max_w' => 200, 'max_h' => 200);

private function storeImage($file) {
  jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');

  $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
  $imageSrc = $file['tmp_name'];
  $extension = strtolower(JFile::getExt($filename));
  // You can add custom images path here
  $imagesPath = JPATH_ROOT . '/media/';

  if (in_array($extension, array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
    // Generate random filename
    $noExt = rand(1000, 9999) . time() . rand(1000, 9999);
    $newFilename = $noExt . '.' . $extension;
    $imageDest = $imagesPath . $newFilename;

    if (JFile::upload($imageSrc, $imageDest)) {
      // Get image size
      list($w, $h, $type) = GetImageSize($imageDest);

      switch ($extension) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
          $srcRes = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageDest);
          break;
        case 'png':
          $srcRes = imagecreatefrompng($imageDest);
          break;
        case 'gif':
          $srcRes = imagecreatefromgif($imageDest);
          break;
        }

        // Calculating thumb size
        if($w > $h) {
          $width_ratio = $this->_thumb['max_w'] / $w;
          $new_width   = $this->_thumb['max_w'];
          $new_height  = $h * $width_ratio;
        } else {
          $height_ratio = $this->_thumb['max_w'] / $h;
          $new_width    = $w * $height_ratio;
          $new_height   = $this->_thumb['max_w'];
        }

        $destRes = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        imagecopyresampled($destRes, $srcRes, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);

        // Creating resized thumbnail
        switch ($extension) {
          case 'jpg':
          case 'jpeg':
            imagejpeg($destRes, $imagesPath . 'thumb_' . $newFilename, 100);
            break;
          case 'png':
            imagepng($destRes, $imagesPath . 'thumb_' . $newFilename, 1);
            break;
          case 'gif':
            imagegif($destRes, $imagesPath . 'thumb_' . $newFilename, 100);
            break;
          }

          imagedestroy($destRes);

          // Delete old image if it was set before

          if (($this->image != "") && JFile::exists($imagesPath . $this->image)) {
        JFile::delete($imagesPath . $this->image);
            JFile::delete($imagesPath . 'thumb_' . $this->image);
          }
          return $newFilename;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

This method returns uploaded file filename, which table stores in 'image' column. It creates two files, one original image and resized thumb with file prefix '_thumb'.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: @d3sel could you use JImage to make  it simpler? https://github.com/elinw/jshell/blob/master/createthumbnails.php

Also why not just use/extend the core JFormFieldMedia?  I'd be careful about uploading without doing the built in dangerous file checks that are built in there i.e. check for malicious code inside the images, check for executable files.  Uploading files is potentially one of the most dangerous things you can do. makeSafe does not actually make a file safe, it is just the first step of many that are used. All it does is strip the name of some illegal characters.

Comment: Hi Elin, of course you're right about file checks / etc, i've only added table part of upload. I use JFormFieldMedia::file which, adds all validation rules needed.

Comment: @di3sel should I replace my codes with your codes or is it fine to let it be? Also i'm confused now where should I place protected $_thumb = array('max_w' => 200, 'max_h' => 200); >> this code?

Answer (score 2):

I used Jimage : https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JImage.html

```
$JImage = new JImage($img_path);
$size_thumb = '150x150';
$JImage->createThumbs($size_thumb,1,$path.'/thumb');
```

Short, simple and efficient.